# dynamically generated field throwing exception in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

i have some dynamically generated fields.When i am inserting values into db not able to get values in the list. Its throwing null value exception. Here is my code.

CSHTML.CS FILE

```
[BindProperty]
public RequestForm RequestForm { get; set; }
public List<RequestForm> RequestFormList { get;set;}
```

OnPost Method

```
if(RequestFormList.Any())
{
    for(var i=0; i<= RequestFormList.Count(); i++)
    {       
        RequestForm.Counter = i;
        _context.Entry(RequestForm).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
}
```

When i click on the Submit button its going to the handler ,but when it reaches RequestFormList.Any(),throwing error. Understood its not passing any value.

********EDITED**********************

Onget Method

```
public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync(string? RequestID)
        {

            UserRole = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userrole");

            RequestStatus = new SelectList(_context.RequestStatus.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "RequestStatusValues", "RequestStatusValues");
            RequestType = new SelectList(_context.RequestType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ReqType", "ReqType");
            Priority = new SelectList(_context.Priority.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "PriorityValues", "PriorityValues");
            
            
            
            Status = new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "No", Text = "No" }
            };
            
            BillType = GetTypeList();


            RequestFormMaster = await _context.RequestFormMaster.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            
            SLAInformation = await _context.SLAInformation.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);                
            YTDRevenue = await _context.YTDRevenue.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            ImplementationInfo = await _context.ImplementationInfo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            ShowRequestChatBox = _context.RequestChatBox.Where(c => c.RequestID == RequestID).OrderBy(c => c.LastModifiedTimeStamp).AsNoTracking().ToList();

            ExistTags = RequestFormMaster.RequestStakeHolders;

            var existtagstring = RequestFormMaster.RequestStakeHolders;
            //after split the existtags, we could get the email list,
            var emaillist = existtagstring.Split(",");
            //we can query the database user table and get the username based on the selected email.
            var existtags = _context.Users.Where(c => emaillist.Contains(c.EmailAddress)).Select(c => new ExistTags()
            {
                Name = c.FirstName + "" + c.LastName, // the full name, firstname + " " + lastname
                Email = c.EmailAddress
            }).ToList();

            var jsonstring = JsonSerializer.Serialize(existtags);
            ViewData["existtag"] = jsonstring;            

            if ((UserRole == "RoleB") && (RequestFormMaster.RequestSubmissionStatus != "Submitted"))
            {
                UserRole = "Submitted"; 
            }
            
            if ((UserRole == "RoleA" || UserRole == "RoleB") && (RequestFormMaster.RequestSubmissionStatus == "Submitted"))
            {
                UserRole = "Implementation";
            }

            return Page();
        }
```

Razor View

```
            <input type="hidden" id="total" value="1" />
            <div class="col-1">
                <label class="control-label mb-0">Bill Type</label>
                <select id="DrpDwnBillType" asp-for="RequestingList[0].BillType" asp-items="@Model.BillType" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label class="control-label mb-0">Origin</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="RequestingList[0].Origin" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label class="control-label mb-0">Destination</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="RequestingList[0].Destination" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label mb-0">Requested Rate</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="LanesRequestingList[0].RequestedRate" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="control-label mb-0">Approval Level</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="RequestingList[0].ApprovalLevel" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-1">
                <label class="control-label mb-0"></label><br />
                <button id="addRow" class="btn btn-success" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "RoleB"?true:false)"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:white;"></i></button>
            </div>
```

Error Pages

[image]

Getting the Billtype values

[image]

And My Userrole is Pricing itself.
All my dropdown list were working fine before making the changes and i was able to access the page. Please let me know if you need full script.

[image]

One more update.When i continue the debug mode the null reference exception is going to next line.

Hi @Rena,

This is my Edit.cshtml.cs

```
namespace SpecialLanePricing.Pages
{
    public class RequestFormEditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public RequestFormEditModel(IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _env = env;
            _context = applicationDbContext;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public RequestFormMaster RequestFormMaster { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public ShipmentProfile ShipmentProfile { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public RatesImplementation RatesImplementation { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public SLAInformation SLAInformation { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public SLPSummary SLPSummary { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public YTDRevenue YTDRevenue { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public ImplementationInfo ImplementationInfo { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public LanesRequestingReduction LanesRequestingReduction { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<LanesRequestingReduction> LanesRequestingReductionList { get;set;}

        [BindProperty]
        public RequestChatBox RequestChatBox { get; set; }
        public RequestFormMaster RequestAlreadyExist { get; set; }
        public string RequestID { get; set; }
        public string DisableField { get; set; }
        public string STCCode { get; set; }
        public string PricingAssignee { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnly { get; set; }
        public SelectList RequestStatus { get; set; }
        public SelectList Priority { get; set; }
        public SelectList ActionForSS { get; set; }
        public SelectList BillingCycle { get; set; }
        public SelectList PaymentTerm { get; set; }
        public SelectList RequestType { get; set; }
        public SelectList BillingCurrency { get; set; }
        public SelectList FTBExistingCustomer { get; set; }
        public SelectList FTBLeadSource { get; set; }
        public SelectList Competitors { get; set; }
        public SelectList B2BByB2C { get; set; }
        public SelectList ShipmentPieceType { get; set; }
        public SelectList BaseContractOffer { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
        public SelectList SSExemptions { get; set; }
        public SelectList BillType { get; set; }
        public IList<RequestChatBox> ShowRequestChatBox { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<IFormFile> ReqSupportingFiles { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public string ExistTags { get; set; }
        public string DisabledField { get; set; }
        
        public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync(string? RequestID)
        {

            UserRole = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userrole");

            RequestStatus = new SelectList(_context.RequestStatus.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "RequestStatusValues", "RequestStatusValues");
            RequestType = new SelectList(_context.RequestType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ReqType", "ReqType");
            Priority = new SelectList(_context.Priority.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "PriorityValues", "PriorityValues");
            ActionForSS = new SelectList(_context.ActionForSalesSupport.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ActionSS", "ActionSS");
            BillingCycle = new SelectList(_context.BillingCycle.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillingCycles", "BillingCycles");
            PaymentTerm = new SelectList(_context.PaymentTerm.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "PaymentTerms", "PaymentTerms");
            BillingCurrency = new SelectList(_context.BillingCurrency.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillingCurrencies", "BillingCurrencies");
            FTBExistingCustomer = new SelectList(_context.FTBExistingCustomer.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "FTBOrExist", "FTBOrExist");
            FTBLeadSource = new SelectList(_context.FTBLeadSource.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "FTBLeadSources", "FTBLeadSources");
            Competitors = new SelectList(_context.Competitors.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "Competitor", "Competitor");
            B2BByB2C = new SelectList(_context.B2BbyB2C.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BtoBBtoC", "BtoBBtoC");
            ShipmentPieceType = new SelectList(_context.ShipmentPieceType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ShipmentPieceTypes", "ShipmentPieceTypes");
            BaseContractOffer = new SelectList(_context.BaseContractOffer.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BaseContractOffers", "BaseContractOffers");
            Status = new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "No", Text = "No" }
            };
            SSExemptions = new SelectList(_context.SSExemptions.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "SAndSExemptions", "SAndSExemptions");
            BillType = GetTypeList();


            RequestFormMaster = await _context.RequestFormMaster.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            ShipmentProfile = await _context.ShipmentProfile.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            RatesImplementation = await _context.RatesImplementation.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            SLAInformation = await _context.SLAInformation.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            SLPSummary = await _context.SLPSummary.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            YTDRevenue = await _context.YTDRevenue.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            ImplementationInfo = await _context.ImplementationInfo.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RequestID == RequestID);
            ShowRequestChatBox = _context.RequestChatBox.Where(c => c.RequestID == RequestID).OrderBy(c => c.LastModifiedTimeStamp).AsNoTracking().ToList();

            ExistTags = RequestFormMaster.RequestStakeHolders;

            var existtagstring = RequestFormMaster.RequestStakeHolders;
            //after split the existtags, we could get the email list,
            var emaillist = existtagstring.Split(",");
            //we can query the database user table and get the username based on the selected email.
            var existtags = _context.Users.Where(c => emaillist.Contains(c.EmailAddress)).Select(c => new ExistTags()
            {
                Name = c.FirstName + "" + c.LastName, // the full name, firstname + " " + lastname
                Email = c.EmailAddress
            }).ToList();

            var jsonstring = JsonSerializer.Serialize(existtags);
            ViewData["existtag"] = jsonstring;            

            if ((UserRole == "Sales") && (RequestFormMaster.RequestSubmissionStatus != "Submitted"))
            {
                UserRole = "SalesSubmitted"; 
            }
            
            if ((UserRole == "Sales Support" || UserRole == "Sales") && (RequestFormMaster.RequestSubmissionStatus == "Submitted"))
            {
                UserRole = "RatesImplementation";
            }
            if (UserRole == "Pricing")
            {
                UserRole = "Pricing";
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitChatAsync(RequestChatBox RequestChatBox)
        {
            RequestChatBox.CommentedUser = HttpContext.Session.GetString("firstname") + " " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("lastname");
            RequestChatBox.UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("emailaddress");
            RequestChatBox.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            RequestChatBox.Comments = RequestChatBox.Comments;
            RequestChatBox.RequestID = RequestChatBox.RequestID;            
            _context.Entry(RequestChatBox).State = EntityState.Added;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            ShowRequestChatBox = _context.RequestChatBox.Where(c => c.RequestID == RequestChatBox.RequestID).OrderBy(c => c.LastModifiedTimeStamp).AsNoTracking().ToList();
            return new OkResult();

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitAsync()
        {
            RequestStatus = new SelectList(_context.RequestStatus.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "RequestStatusValues", "RequestStatusValues");
            RequestType = new SelectList(_context.RequestType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ReqType", "ReqType");
            Priority = new SelectList(_context.Priority.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "PriorityValues", "PriorityValues");
            ActionForSS = new SelectList(_context.ActionForSalesSupport.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ActionSS", "ActionSS");
            BillingCycle = new SelectList(_context.BillingCycle.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillingCycles", "BillingCycles");
            PaymentTerm = new SelectList(_context.PaymentTerm.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "PaymentTerms", "PaymentTerms");
            BillingCurrency = new SelectList(_context.BillingCurrency.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillingCurrencies", "BillingCurrencies");
            FTBExistingCustomer = new SelectList(_context.FTBExistingCustomer.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "FTBOrExist", "FTBOrExist");
            FTBLeadSource = new SelectList(_context.FTBLeadSource.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "FTBLeadSources", "FTBLeadSources");
            Competitors = new SelectList(_context.Competitors.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "Competitor", "Competitor");
            B2BByB2C = new SelectList(_context.B2BbyB2C.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BtoBBtoC", "BtoBBtoC");
            ShipmentPieceType = new SelectList(_context.ShipmentPieceType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "ShipmentPieceTypes", "ShipmentPieceTypes");
            BaseContractOffer = new SelectList(_context.BaseContractOffer.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BaseContractOffers", "BaseContractOffers");
            Status = new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "No", Text = "No" }
            };
            SSExemptions = new SelectList(_context.SSExemptions.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "SAndSExemptions", "SAndSExemptions");
            BillType = new SelectList(_context.BillType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillTypes", "BillTypes");
            
            
            //RequestFormMaster.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID.Trim();
            //RequestFormMaster.PricingAssignee = RequestFormMaster.PricingAssignee.Trim();
            //RequestFormMaster.PricingAssigneeEmail = RequestFormMaster.PricingAssigneeEmail.Trim();
            //RequestFormMaster.RequestStakeHolders = Request.Form["addedTags"];

            if ((RequestFormMaster.Priority == "Priority “A” – 2 Business Days") || (RequestFormMaster.Priority == "Priority “B” – 4 Business Days"))
            {
                DateTime RequestDeadLine = Convert.ToDateTime(RequestFormMaster.RequestDeadLine);
                RequestFormMaster.RequestDeadLine = RequestDeadLine;
            }
            else
            {
                RequestFormMaster.RequestDeadLine = RequestFormMaster.RequestDeadLine;
            }
            if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == null))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Requestor";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 1;
            }
            else if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Pricing Review") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "OMS Submission") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "KIWI+ Submission") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "KAP Analysis"))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Assignee";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 2;
            }
            else if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Cross BU Alignment") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "OARs Form Alignment"))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Other Functions";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 3;
            }
            else if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Analysis Review") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Local TRB Review") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "AP-TRB Review"))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Approver";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 4;
            }
            else if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Approved by Pricing Executive") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Approved by Pricing Manager") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Approved Local-TRB") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Approved by AP-TRB") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Rejected") || (RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Customer Acceptance & Implementation"))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Completed";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 5;
            }
            else if ((RequestFormMaster.RequestStatus == "Implementation Approval (KIWI+)"))
            {
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarStatus = "Implemented";
                RequestFormMaster.ProgressBarCounter = 5;
            }

            RequestFormMaster.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("firstname") + " " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("lastname");
            _context.Entry(RequestFormMaster).State = EntityState.Modified;

            ShipmentProfile.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            ShipmentProfile.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("firstname") + " " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("lastname");
            ShipmentProfile.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(ShipmentProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            RatesImplementation.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            RatesImplementation.OpportunityID = RequestFormMaster.OppurtunityID;
            RatesImplementation.CompanyName = RequestFormMaster.CustomerName;
            RatesImplementation.SiteID = RequestFormMaster.SiteID;
            RatesImplementation.AGCMACCode = RequestFormMaster.AGCMACCode;
            RatesImplementation.BillingCycle = RequestFormMaster.BillingCycleName;
            RatesImplementation.PaymentTerms = RequestFormMaster.PaymentTermName;
            RatesImplementation.ExemptionsSS = ShipmentProfile.SSExemptions;
            RatesImplementation.AccountNumbers = RequestFormMaster.AccountsInScope;
            RatesImplementation.LastModifiedTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(RatesImplementation).State = EntityState.Modified;

            SLAInformation.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            SLAInformation.SalesDateOfSubmission = DateTime.Now;
            SLAInformation.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(SLAInformation).State = EntityState.Modified;

            SLPSummary.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            SLPSummary.CustomerName = RequestFormMaster.CustomerName;
            SLPSummary.Commodity = ShipmentProfile.Commodity;
            SLPSummary.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(SLPSummary).State = EntityState.Modified;

            YTDRevenue.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            YTDRevenue.PricingOwnership = RequestFormMaster.PricingAssignee;
            YTDRevenue.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(YTDRevenue).State = EntityState.Modified;

            ImplementationInfo.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
            ImplementationInfo.CPAID = RequestFormMaster.CPAID;
            ImplementationInfo.LastModifiedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Entry(ImplementationInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;

            if (LanesRequestingReductionList.Any())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= LanesRequestingReductionList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    LanesRequestingReduction.RequestID = RequestFormMaster.RequestID;
                    LanesRequestingReduction.Counter = i;
                    _context.Entry(LanesRequestingReduction).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["ReqSubmitted"] = "Submitted";
            var foldername = RequestFormMaster.RequestID.ToString();
            var DirectoryPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents", foldername);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirectoryPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryPath);
            }
            if (ReqSupportingFiles != null || ReqSupportingFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (IFormFile upload in ReqSupportingFiles)
                {
                    i++;
                    // Upload file to server folder
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName).ToLower();
                    if ((ext == ".ppt") || (ext == ".pptx") || (ext == ".xls") || (ext == "xlsx"))
                    {
                        var filesave = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents", foldername, i + "_" + upload.FileName);
                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filesave))
                        {
                            await upload.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //SendEmailAsync();
            //OnPostUploadFiles(fileData, RequestID);
            return RedirectToPage("/RequestSummary");

            //return Page();
        }

        public JsonResult OnGetSearchValue(string search)
        {
            List<Users> allsearch = new List<Users>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                allsearch = _context.Users.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(search) || x.EmailAddress.Equals(search)).ToList();
            }
            return new JsonResult(allsearch);
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetDynamicTypeList()
        {
            return new JsonResult(GetTypeList());
        }

        public SelectList GetTypeList()
        {
            SelectList BillTypeValues = new SelectList(_context.BillType.OrderBy(e => e.ID), "BillTypes", "BillTypes");
            return BillTypeValues;
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks,
Teena

Comment: Hi @Teena, Could you please debug your code and check if `UserRole ` and `BillType` contain data? I saw you get session here: `HttpContext.Session.GetString("userrole");`. Please be sure you set the session in any place.  Also I saw you set BillType by `GetTypeList()` method. Be sure it returns any data.

Comment: Also, for `RequestStatus ` ,`RequestType ` and `Priority `, this maybe used to populate your dropdownlist, be sure it contains value. Also be sure you write the correct property name for the dataField and textField in `SelectList`.

Comment: Your backend code contains too many properties which do not share in your View. If Any of them do not contain data will cause null reference error. Any way, just remember one thing is, if you use any like: `@Model.XXX`, you need make sure your backend has set the value for it.

Comment: Hi @Rena, i have added some screenshots in my question. Its showing exactly where i have the issue.Could please check it.

Comment: Hi @Teena, please share the  entire code in screenshot, what is your `asp-items` for select?

Comment: Your screenshot indicates `asp-items` does not contain value or it is not correctly set. How do you set the asp-items.

Comment: Hi @Rena,i have shared a recent screenshot. My asp-items is having value.Could you please check it

Comment: So amazing. If they all have value, it will not receive null reference error. Did you use `public class IndexModel : PageModel` in your .cs file and use `@model IndexModel` in your cshtml file. Coud you please share how do you define `LanesRequestingReductionList`?

Comment: Hi @Rena, i have copied my entire cshtml.cs file.Could you please checvk.Let me know if you need my Model class file also.

Comment: Also share the whole view pls.  What if you change all the  `asp-for` to `name`? Does it also make error? It is so amazing that asp-for will never get null reference exception because it is mainly generate the id and name in html no matter contains value or not.

Comment: Hi @Rena, my whole razor view has almost 1000 lines of codes.shall i share that block of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239999/discussion-between-rena-and-teena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i click on the Submit button its going to the handler ,but when
> it reaches RequestFormList.Any(),throwing error. Understood its not
> passing any value.

You need change two things to achieve your requirement:

- Model binding system bind the property by name attribute.

For list model the name should be `Model[index].propertyName`. In your case, the name should be: `RequestFormList[index].propertyName` instead of `RequestForm.propertyName_index`.

- `[BindProperty]` only supports for one property, if you want to bind all the properties in your PageModel, you need add `[BindProperty]` to each property or add `[BindProperties]` to PageModel:

  ```
  [BindProperty]
  public RequestForm RequestForm { get; set; }
  [BindProperty]
  public List<RequestForm> RequestFormList { get;set;}
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  [BindProperties]
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {.....}
  ```

**Besides, your html code uses `asp-for="RequestForm.RequestRate_0"`  but your success function manually add code `name="RequestForm.RequestedRate_'`, their property names are not same**.

A whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class RequestForm
{
    public string BillType { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string RequestRate { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <div id="newRow" class="form-row mt-2">
        <input type="hidden" id="total" value="1" />
        <div class="col-1">
            <label class="control-label mb-0">Bill Type</label>
            <select id="DrpDwnBillType" asp-for="RequestFormList[0].BillType" asp-items="@Model.BillType" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <label class="control-label mb-0">Origin</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="RequestFormList[0].Origin" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <label class="control-label mb-0">Destination</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="RequestFormList[0].Destination" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <label class="control-label mb-0">Requested Rate</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="RequestFormList[0].RequestRate" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label class="control-label mb-0">Approval Level</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="RequestFormList[0].ApprovalLevel" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <label class="control-label mb-0"></label><br />
            <button id="addRow" class="btn btn-success" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "Pricing"?true:false)"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:white;"></i></button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

JS in page:

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var rowCount = parseInt($("#total").val());
    rowCount++;
    $("#total").val(rowCount);
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "?handler=DynamicTypeList",    //url depends on yourself...
        success: function (data) {
            //add new select element:
            var newselect = '<select id="DrpDwnBillType" name="RequestFormList[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].BillType" class="form-control form-control-sm">'
            newselect += '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                newselect += `<option value="${item.value}">${item.text}</option>`;
            });
            newselect += "</select>";
            //generate the new form group
            var html = '';
            html += '<div id="inputRow" class="form-row mt-1">';
            html += '<div class="col-1">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0" >Bill Type</label >';
            html += newselect;          
            html += '</div >';
            html += '<div class="col-1">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0" >Origin</label >';
            html += '<input type="text" name="RequestFormList[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].Origin" class="form-control form-control-sm" />';
            html += '</div >';
            html += '<div class="col-1">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0" >Destination</label >';
            html += '<input type="text"  name="RequestFormList[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].Destination" class="form-control form-control-sm" />';
            html += '</div >';          
            html += '<div class="col-2">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0" >Requested Rate</label >';
            html += '<input type="text"name="RequestFormList[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].RequestedRate" class="form-control form-control-sm" />';
            html += '</div >';
            html += '<div class="col-2">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0" >Approval Level</label >';
            html += '<input type="text" name="RequestFormList[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].ApprovalLevel" class="form-control form-control-sm" />';
            html += '</div >';
            html += '<div class="col-1">';
            html += '<label class="control-label mb-0"></label><br />';
            html += '<button id="removeRow" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:white;"></i></button>';
            html += '</div>';
            //html += '<input type="number" name="[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].Age"  />';
            //add more inputs here...
            //html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#newRow').after(html);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });


});
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    var rowCount = parseInt($("#total").val());
    rowCount--;
    $("#total").val(rowCount);
    $(this).closest('#inputRow').remove();
});
</script>
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    [BindProperty]
    public RequestForm RequestForm { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<RequestForm> RequestFormList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> BillType { get; set; }

    public string UserRole { get; set; } //update code here...
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        BillType = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){Text="Bill1",Value="1"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="Bill2",Value="2"}
        };

        UserRole = "Pricing";   //update code here...
        return Page();
    }
    public IActionResult OnGetDynamicTypeList()
    {
        var data = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){Text="aa",Value="1"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="bb",Value="2"},
            new SelectListItem(){Text="cc",Value="3"}
        };
        return new JsonResult(data);
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        //.....
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.Now im getting System Null Referenece Exception at Razor page. I understood that since there are no values in the list its throwing error.At first when you click on the edit page there wont be anything in the page,so at that time i cannot use the list ryt?

Comment: Hi @Teena, Null Referenece Exception means you do not have data if you use something like: `@Model.Property`  to display the data. If you simply use asp-for="PropertyName", it does not matter you set the data or not. Could you mind share your code or share with me which line causes null reference?

Comment: Hi @Teena, BTW, when did this error message appear? After submit to the post handler?

Comment: when im accessing the page im getting this error

Comment: Could you please edit your question to share your OnGet method and your updated View?

Comment: Hi @Teena,If your View is the same as mine. Please check if you set value for BillType. Also, I forget to tell you I remove the `UserRole` for easy testing. Be sure you have set value for `UserRole` in `OnGet` method.   I have updated my answer and include the `UserRole`. Any problems you can follow up.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I have added my Onget Method and Razor View. This Page will be used by more than 2 userroles.If i set userole in my on get method will it screw up my other fields since i have more than 50 fields in this page.Thanks Teena

Comment: Ok. Got it. Any way for the nullable reference error we can only tell you how to trouble shooting because we cannot debug your code. I have shared which line you need check, please debug yourself and wait for your feedback.

Comment: Maybe your view contains many code. Just remember one thing is, if you use any like: `@Model.XXX`, you need make sure your backend has set the value for it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the `RequestFormList` as part of its declaration then it will never be null:

`public List<RequestForm> RequestFormList { get;set;} = new List<RequestForm>();`

Comment: Brand, Thanks for the reply. The error has gone now.But i am not able to pass the list values.It showing the count as 0. I checked the name attribute of the fields.First row input field name is RequestForm.BillType_0 and second row field name is RequestForm.BillType_1 .